# Trying to get my head wrapped around Conditional NULL syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a ASP.NET search page that displays a SQL bound ListView after a Search button is clicked. In the EmptyDataTemplate, I've got an asp label based on the ID they searched for in a message. "No results found for " kinda thing.

Here's my original codebehind for the button click:

```
protected void btnSearch_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    Label lbl = (Label)lvMatOrders.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("lblProjectID");
    if (lbl != null)  // this means EmptyDataTemplate is used, else ItemTemplate
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProjectID.Text))
        {
            lbl.Text = "#####";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.Text = txtProjectID.Text;
        }

    }
}
```

Am I correct in understanding that I can reduce it down to the following?

```
Label lbl = (Label)lvMatOrders.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("lblProjectID");
lbl?.Text = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProjectID.Text)) ? "#####" : txtProjectID.Text;
```

The main goal here is to make sure that the code that attempts to assign either the "#####" or txtProjectID.Text to lbl.Text doesn't get executed if the page already has results from a previous search displayed as the page isn't showing the EmptyDataTemplate and thus no lblProjectID to assign the text to.

Will the `lbl?.Text` line be attempted if the page is in ItemTemplate mode?

Comment: the set won't be attempted if the lbl is `null`.

Comment: I think `lbl?.Text = ` is not supported. Only getters and method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the code will not even compile, you will get the error *"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"*

You can not use the `.?` operator on the left hand side of a equals sign, only the right hand side.

Comment: So I would still need something like this:
`if (lbl != null) {lbl.Text = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProjectID.Text)) ? "#####" : txtProjectID.Text;}`

Comment: Yes. The only way you could use it is if `lbl` had a `SetText(string text)` method, you could then call it like `lbl?.SetText((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProjectID.Text)) ? "#####" : txtProjectID.Text);`, but if you are going to use `lbl.Text = ...` you must use the `lbl != null` check.

Comment: Note, that `SetText` could be a extension method if you wanted.

Comment: That's good enough for me. With all the if null checks, I figured at least a good chunk of that original code could be reduced to a couple of lines.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Isn't that irony? If we use "Java" `Get/Set` method style, we could use the null conditional operator. And taking into account that property `Text` is just sugar for `get_Text` / `set_Text` methods :)